# HTML Dropdown - Get data from two tables into optgroup & list item

Tags: html, mysql

I am using two tables called `cat_parent` where Parent categories are saved & `cat_sub` where Category items are saved. 
Following are the database structures.

**cat_parent**

```
Column           Column Type    Null
cat_id             int(11)       No
category_name    varchar(355)    No
```

**cat_sub**

```
Column              Column Type        Null
sub_cat_id            int(11)           No
profile_category      int(10)           No
sub_cat_name         varchar(355)       No
```

Now I want to get all the data into one html dropdown list.
In category_name in cat_parent table should appear as optgroup for every category. Under optgroup, every category items belonging to parent category should appear.

Example.

```
<select name="sample">
  <optgroup label="Cars"> // Data from cat_parent
  <option>Benz</option> // Data from cat_sub
  <option>Toyota</option> // Data from cat_sub
  <optgroup label="Mobile Phones"> // Data from cat_parent
  <option>Samsung</option> // Data from cat_sub
  <option>Nokia</option> // Data from cat_sub
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will first of all need a foreign key in your cat_sub table (I called it **parent_id** here).

**Query**

```
SELECT   cat_sub.sub_cat_name,
         cat_par.category_name
FROM cat_sub
    JOIN cat_par ON
        cat_par.cat_id = cat_sub.parent_id
```

Then in your code (doesn't really matter what language you are using) you can loop over all the rows and put all the subcategories in an associative hash where the main key is the parent key with an array of subcategories. Next print the result to your html.

**PHP [Not tested, so could contain errors. PS: logic should be split into different pages!]**

```
#Query
$query= "SELECT   cat_sub.sub_cat_name,
                  cat_par.category_name
         FROM cat_sub
         JOIN cat_par ON
             cat_par.cat_id = cat_sub.parent_id";

#Connection
$connection = new \PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;port=$db_port", $db_user, $db_pass);

#Statement
$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$result = $stmt->execute();
if(!$result){
    throw new \Exception($query);
}
$objects = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

#print
echo "<select>";
$parent_cat="";
foreach($objects as $object){
   if($parent_cat != $object["category_name"]){
        $parent_cat = $object["category_name"];
        echo "<optgroup label='".$object["category_name"]."'>";
   }
   echo "<option>".$object["sub_cat_name"]."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

I hope that this will help you?

Comment: Ok. Joining part is ok. After the joining, how do I print the results in list menu? How do I print optgroup?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: PHP & MYSQL for Database

Comment: I added my answer post with php code (not tested, so it can contain some errors: but the logic should be correct)